# Convert JS variable to JSTL

Tags: javascript, jsp, jstl

I have a javascript variable. I'd like to assign the value of it to JSTL variable.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: JavaScript runs in the client browser; JSTL runs on the server before the page contents are transmitted to the client.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible since JavaScript is run in the client browser and JSTL in the server.
Your JavaScript must send the value to a servlet, one way or another.

Comment: He wants to assign the JavaScript value to the JSTL variable; your answer does the opposite (JSTL to JavaScript).

Comment: Thx, i was not sure since this can work only one way... I fixed my answer.